# How to get records from multiple databases in couchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using multiple CouchDB databases(separate database per a registered user) in my current ongoing web and mobile application project.

Now I need to get all the records from all the created databases.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The statement "need to get all the records" needs clarification.  Regardless I'll take a stab - replicating the user DB's to a monolith DB would allow more time to focus on mining the monolith for information rather than crafting code to do what replication provides.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB does not provide a multi-database query mechanism. You should query each database one-by-one to collect that information.

This is a drawback of the db-per-user approach as it does not provide an aggregated view of the information that the application is collecting.

You can explore to implement a consolidation process that aggregates the documents of each user db into a single db using the built-in replication functionality.